# How to apply filters in get builds list VSTS REST API?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get a builds list from VSTS using power shell as written here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1
My uri is:

```
https://tfs.*****.com/STS/FORIS_Mobile/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&definitions=6331&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded&tagFilters='Rejected'&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending
```

I send a request like this:

```
$buildsOverview = Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $buildsUrl | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And I have result without filters `definitions=6331` and `tagFilters='Rejected'`.

What am I doing wrong with this request?

**UPD**
Here is the way $buildsUrl constructing:

```
$buildsUrlBase = "$tfsConnectString/$teamProjectName/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1"
$buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&definitions=" +  $definitionIds.ToString() + "&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded&maxBuildsPerDefinition=$BuildsPerDef&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending"    

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($buildQuality) -ne $true) 
{
    $buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&tagFilters='$buildQuality'"
}
$buildsUrlBase = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString($buildsUrlBase)
```

Actual string with my build definition id was in the question.

Also I've tried use Invoke-RestMethod:

```
$buildsOverview = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -UseDefaultCredential
```

But with the same results

Comment: Could-you please show how you affect the variable $buildsUrl ? You should also use Invoke-RestMethod (without the ConvertFrom-Json) to directly get an object.

Comment: Here is the way $buildsUrl constructing:

$buildsUrlBase = "$tfsConnectString/$teamProjectName/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1"
 $buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&definitions=" +  $definitionIds.ToString() + "&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded&maxBuildsPerDefinition=$BuildsPerDef&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending"    
 
 if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($buildQuality) -ne $true) 
 {
  $buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&tagFilters='$buildQuality'"
 }
 $buildsUrlBase = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString($buildsUrlBase)

Actual string with my build definition id was in the question.

Comment: Also i`ve tryed use Invoke-RestMethod:
    $buildsOverview = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -UseDefaultCredential

But with the same results

Comment: Don't know if it's the problem but when I past the first URL in Chrome `'` characters are converted to `%27`. But EscapeUriString doesn't do that. You may try to use `$buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&tagFilters=%27$buildQuality%27"` and suppress the `$buildsUrlBase = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString($buildsUrlBase)` line.

Comment: It gives the same result for me, both filters `definitions=6331` and `tagFilters=%27Rejected%27` don`t works

Comment: Just to be sure about the question: if you enter the first url you gave in a navigator, is the result correct ?

Comment: For the tagFilters parameter, you should not use `'`: `$buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&tagFilters=$buildQuality"`

Comment: Is _6331_ the correct ID of your Build definition (the one shown in the url of the Build Definition with parameter `definitionId`)?

Comment: Yes, it`s correct

Comment: Which one of my 3 previous comments was correct ? :-) Could you please try without the single quotes arround the tagFilters value ?

Comment: ID 6331 for build definition is correct =) With the single quotes still the same result - returns 12 builds with diffenet definitions and different tags or without any tags =(

Comment: Very strange ... Could you please try this url in a browser: `https://tfs.mtsit.com/STS/FORIS_Mobile/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1&statusFilter=completed&tagFilters=Rejected&definitions=6331&resultFilter=succeeded&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending` ? I reproduced your request on VSTS and it works (I only get 1 entry).

Comment: Finaly, it works correct with api-version=2.0 and without single quotes for tags. Thank you for help!

Comment: Great ! Could-you validate the answer bellow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments the solution is the following:

- Use the 2.0 version of the API
- Do not use quotes around tag(s)

URL: `https://tfs.*****.com/STS/FORIS_Mobile/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&statusFilter=completed&tagFilters=Rejected&definitions=6331&resultFilter=succeeded&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending`

And the code to generate it:

```
$buildsUrlBase = "$tfsConnectString/$teamProjectName/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&definitions=" +  $definitionIds.ToString() + "&statusFilter=completed&resultFilter=succeeded&maxBuildsPerDefinition=$BuildsPerDef&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending"    

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($buildQuality) -ne $true) 
{
    $buildsUrlBase = "$buildsUrlBase&tagFilters=$buildQuality"
}
$buildsUrlBase = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString($buildsUrlBase)
```